# Meaning of "to lay off of someone"

Tags: meaning-in-context, definition

According to the Merriam-Webster dictionary, one of the meanings of "to lay off" is :

> to lay off : to leave undisturbed.

How would this definition fit within the context "to *lay off* of him" for example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the context you are referring to means to *leave someone alone* or to *stop bothering* or even *stop hurting/attacking someone*.

> Example:
>   Person 1: "It's Person 2's fault!"
>   Person 3: "Hey, lay off him!"

"Lay off *of* someone" is just an idiomatic variation. It sounds more like AmEng than BrEng to me and in my opinion not grammatically correct (or at the very least is a *[tautology](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/off_of)*), but from my experience of US culture, it is commonly spoken.

In a very different context "lay-off" can also mean to terminate someone's employment, although this would normally be phrased "lay someone off".

Comment: Would "lay off him" have the same meaning ? Meaning, is the "of" in this context mandatory ?

Comment: @Norbert I've just added that into my answer - it means the same, it is just an idiomatic variation, not grammatically correct in my opinion, but colloquial.

Comment: *Lay off **of** him* sounds grammatical to me. In fact, not using the preposition doesn't fit standard grammatical constructions. It's *lie on top **of** him* (not *lie on top him*) or *get down **from** him* (not *get down him*). Dropping the preposition is idiomatic—but far from *necessary*.

Comment: @JasonBassford You never hear it in BrEng, it seems like an Americanism. It isn't the same as "get down *from*", because there are different levels of "down". Getting "off *something*" doesn't allow for any half-measure and the "of" is redundant. See: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/off_of